# Something like 'SubArray' but with more than one parent array?

Tags: julia

I'm looking for something like this:

```
virtualArray = VirtualArray((parent1,2:5,1:3), (parent2,1:15,5:7))
```

which would construct something like the SubArray, except with contributions from two or more parent arrays.

The point is to combine two or more array-like data sources without allocating additional memory.

I'm aware of both the SubArray and View types, which provide access to a slice of a parent array.  I've also come across the DistributedArray and SharedArray, which looks like I could hack to make do what I want, but that doesn't seem to be the intended purpose of these types.

I could try to implement myself, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if someone else has already done it, probably much better than I could at this point.

Comment: I suppose one solution would be something like vhcat or vvcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer: there's no complete solution for this at the moment.  It's a tricky problem to make both fast and generalized.  I [asked this question](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/julia-users/0R9jTb0hTTI) recently on julia-users... you might find some ideas there.